# Load sequencing pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some pictures I want them to have to organize the page every 10 seconds.

As follows:

- Photo 1 fully loaded
- Wait 10 seconds
- After photo 1, photo 2 is fully loaded
- Wait 10 seconds
- After Photo 2, Photo 3 is fully loaded
- Wait 10 seconds

, ...

Until we finish all photos.

my problem :

method load don't work & 
i don't know method for waiting

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jq.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images=["images/0.jpg",
                    "images/1.jpg",
                    "images/2.jpg",
                    "images/3.jpg",
                    "images/4.jpg",
                    "images/5.jpg",
                    "images/6.jpg",
                    "images/7.jpg",
                    "images/8.jpg",
                    "images/9.jpg",
                    "images/10.jpg"
                ];
        for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            var imgtag = '<img src='+images[i]+' />';
            $(imgtag).load(function() {
                $('div').append(imgtag);
                //Wait 10 sec   ==> Is there a function to Waiting :-??
            }
       }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to wait for the DOM ready event, then use a recursive callback :

```
$(function() {   // on DOM ready

var images = [
    "images/0.jpg",
    "images/1.jpg",
    "images/2.jpg",
    "images/3.jpg",
    "images/4.jpg",
    "images/5.jpg",
    "images/6.jpg",
    "images/7.jpg",
    "images/8.jpg",
    "images/9.jpg",
    "images/10.jpg"
];

(function loadImg(index) {
    if (index >= images.length) return;  // no more image to load

    $('#divId').append( $('<img />').attr('src', srcImg).load(function() {
        // invoke this function again in 10 secs incrementing index by 1
        setTimeout(function() { loadImg(index + 1); }, 10000);
    }) );

})(0);   // initiate loading sequence with first image index

});
```

Comment: thanks,
Some pictures over last anywhere from 10 seconds to be loaded
I want to load next picture only when the current picture is loaded completely.
What is your solution to this problem?

Comment: just bind a load event to you rnewly created image and all your next funciton after the specified timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` function.

```
var images=["images/0.jpg",
                    "images/1.jpg",
                    "images/2.jpg",
                    "images/3.jpg",
                    "images/4.jpg",
                    "images/5.jpg",
                    "images/6.jpg",
                    "images/7.jpg",
                    "images/8.jpg",
                    "images/9.jpg",
                    "images/10.jpg"
                ];
var count = 0;
function loadImage() {
  if (count < images.length) {
    var imgtag = '<img src='+images[count]+' />';
    $('div').append(imgtag);
    count++;
  }
}

setInterval(loadImage, 10000);
```

Comment: Would go beyond 10. I recommend a recursive setTimeout with a conditional on count <= images.lenght

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj thanks, :x 
some images are very large (size > 2mb), and display it, While don't loaded complately :(

what is your solution